# What is the best way to load Ruby classes into an application?

Tags: ruby

Currently I am loading Ruby classes into each class file using the require command, for example:

```
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'observation_worker')
require File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'log_worker')
```

For each class I am defining the classes it requires. It would be great if I could do this at the entry point to my application.

Is there an easy way to load all the Ruby classes at the start of an application?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have a somewhat clear directory structure of where your code goes you could add specific directory paths to the load path like

```
$LOAD_PATH.unshift( File.join( File.dirname(__FILE__), 'lib' ) )
```

then in other parts of your code you could require from a relative path like so:

```
require 'observation_worker'
require 'logger_worker'
```

or if you have folders within lib you could even do

```
require 'workers/observation'
require 'workers/logger'
```

This is probably the cleanest way to handle loading within a library's context in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure I fully understand, since you will always have to tell your program what files it needs, but you could do something like:

```
Dir["#{File.dirname(__FILE__)}/*.rb"].each { |f| require(f) }
```

Which will include all .rb files from the directory of the current file.
Although if you ever start using RDoc, it will not be happy with you.

It's generally not a bad thing to list your requires explicitly, it makes it clear to other developers reading your code what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option I like using.

http://github.com/dyoder/autocode/tree/master

From the github doc

```
  require 'autocode'

  module Application
    include AutoCode
    auto_load true, :directories => [ :configurations, :models, :views, :controllers ]
  end
```

This will attempt to load code dynamically from the given directories, using the module name to determine which 
directory to look in. Thus, Application::CustomerModel could load the file models/customer_model.rb.

Also, you can check out the way rails boots.

Comment: for reference [autocode](http://github.com/dyoder/autocode/tree/master) is "This respository is no longer in use will be removed shortly. Please use the waves/autocode repository."

Answer (score 1):

*As commented by jtzero, autoload has been deprecated*

---

You still need to specify what to load, but you can try `autoload`.

```
autoload :Module, "module"
```

When the constant `Module` is first used the file `"module"` will be `require`d automatically.

Comment: for reference, autoload is [deprecated](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/3036681)

Answer (score 1):

checkout this class loader

http://github.com/alexeypetrushin/class_loader

suppose you have the following directory structure

```
/your_app
    /lib            
        /animals
            /dog.rb
        /zoo.rb
```

just point ClassLoader to the root of your App, it will find and loads all other classes automatically

```
require 'class_loader'
autoload_dir '/your_app/lib'

Zoo.add Animals::Dog.new # <= all classes loaded automatically
```